# C# - How to insert data from SQL table to Excel template using Console Application

Tags: c#, excel, console

I have different SQL tables that I need to export to Excel file.
I created a blank Excel Template with cell formatting but no data, even column names.

Is there a way to insert data from SQL table with undefined numbers of columns to an existing Excel Template? 
I found this code, but it's not working:

```
        string fileName = @"C:\test.xls";
        string connectionString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                "Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=0'", fileName);

        using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            cn.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [Sheet1$] " +
                 "VALUES(@value1, @value2, @value3, @value4)", cn);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", "Key1");
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value2", "Sample1");
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value3", 1);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value4", 9);
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on `but it's not working`? What exactly is happening? Are you getting error? What error? Which line of code gives you error?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I am getting an error "Number of query values and destination fields are not the same." Also, this code is for static data. I would like to import data to Excel from Sql table. Thank you very much

Comment: The error says that you are not passing the same number of values in INSERT statement as the number of columns in `Sheet`$`. You need to reverify and make sure that you have the correct number of values in INSERT statement.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, that's actually the problem because I need to insert data to Excel without defining the numbers of columns. I'll be using the same template for different tables with different columns.

Comment: You should definitely try out ClosedXML. I have been using it for ages and is the best C# to Excel package out there in my opinion. https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML